# the controller only works from the form, if the route in the <a> tag does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

coment-reject and other similar routes do not get into the controller and do not change records in the database, what's the problem? When the route is written in the action attribute of the form, everything runs fine.

comments.blade.php

```
@extends('dashboard')
@section('content')
    <div class="comments-block">
        @if($comments)
            @foreach ($comments as $comment)
                @if ($comment->parent_id != 0)
                    <p> {{ $comments[$comment->parent_id-1]->name }}</p>
                @endif
            <div class="comment-block-actions">
                <h1>{{$comment->text}}</h1>
                <a class = "approve-comment" href="{{ route('comments-approving', $comment->id) }}">approve</a><br/>
                <a class = "reject-comment" href="{{ route('comments-rejecting', $comment->id) }}">reject</a><br/>
                <a class = "delete-comment" href="{{ route('comments-deleting', $comment->id) }}">delete</a><br/>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
    Route::post('/commend-approved-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'approveComment'])->name('comments-approving');
    Route::post('/comment-rejected-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'rejectComment'])->name('comments-rejecting');
    Route::post('/comment-deleted-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'deleteComment'])->name('comments-deleting');
```

adminCOntroller.php

````
    public function approveComment($id)
    {
        $comment = comments::find($id);
        $comment->status = 'publish';
        $comment->save();
    }

    public function rejectComment($id)
    {
        $comment = comments::find($id);
        $comment->status = 'pending';
        $comment->save();
    }

    public function deleteComment($id)
    {
        comments::find($id)->delete();
    }```
````

Comment: The problem is that you are doing GET requests but you defined POST requests in the routes

Comment: Change your route to get, `Route::post…` to `Route::get…`

Comment: follows the link but does not change post status in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was not working because was used other route, to repair this i need to move this 3
route to the top of file

before:

```
Route::prefix("/home")->group(function () {

         
    Route::get('/posts', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewPosts'])->name('posts');
    Route::get('/posts/edit-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editPost'])->name('editPost');
    Route::post('/posts/edit-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editPostPublish'])->name('editPostPublish');
    Route::get('/posts/new-post', [admin\adminController::class, 'postForm'])->name('postForm');
    Route::post('/posts/new-post/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'postPosting'])->name('postPosting');
    Route::get('/new-city', [admin\adminController::class, 'cityForm'])->name('cityForm');
    Route::post('/new-city/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'cityPost'])->name('cityPost');
    Route::get('/comments', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewComments'])->name('comments-view');
    Route::get('/category/new', [admin\adminController::class, 'newCategory'])->name('new-categories');
    Route::get('/taxonomy/new', [admin\adminController::class, 'newTaxonomy'])->name('new-taxonomy');
    Route::post('/success-cat', [admin\adminController::class, 'postCategory'])->name('success-cat');
    Route::post('/success-tax', [admin\adminController::class, 'postTaxonomy'])->name('success-tax');
    Route::get('/{postType}', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewAdvertisement'])->name('view-advertisement');
    Route::get('/{postType}/{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editAdvertisement'])->name('edit-advertisement');
    Route::post('/{postType}/{id}/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'editAdvertisementSuccess'])->name('success');
    Route::post('/{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'deleteAdvertisement'])->name('delete-adv');
    Route::get('/commend-approved-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'approveComment'])->name('comments-approving');
    Route::get('/comment-rejected-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'rejectComment'])->name('comments-rejecting');
    Route::get('/comment-deleted-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'deleteComment'])->name('comments-deleting');

});
```

after:

````
Route::prefix("/home")->group(function () {

    Route::get('/commend-approved-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'approveComment'])->name('comments-approving');
    Route::get('/comment-rejected-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'rejectComment'])->name('comments-rejecting');
    Route::get('/comment-deleted-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'deleteComment'])->name('comments-deleting');
    Route::get('/posts', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewPosts'])->name('posts');
    Route::get('/posts/edit-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editPost'])->name('editPost');
    Route::post('/posts/edit-{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editPostPublish'])->name('editPostPublish');
    Route::get('/posts/new-post', [admin\adminController::class, 'postForm'])->name('postForm');
    Route::post('/posts/new-post/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'postPosting'])->name('postPosting');
    Route::get('/new-city', [admin\adminController::class, 'cityForm'])->name('cityForm');
    Route::post('/new-city/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'cityPost'])->name('cityPost');
    Route::get('/comments', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewComments'])->name('comments-view');
    Route::get('/category/new', [admin\adminController::class, 'newCategory'])->name('new-categories');
    Route::get('/taxonomy/new', [admin\adminController::class, 'newTaxonomy'])->name('new-taxonomy');
    Route::post('/success-cat', [admin\adminController::class, 'postCategory'])->name('success-cat');
    Route::post('/success-tax', [admin\adminController::class, 'postTaxonomy'])->name('success-tax');
    Route::get('/{postType}', [admin\adminController::class, 'viewAdvertisement'])->name('view-advertisement');
    Route::get('/{postType}/{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'editAdvertisement'])->name('edit-advertisement');
    Route::post('/{postType}/{id}/success', [admin\adminController::class, 'editAdvertisementSuccess'])->name('success');
    Route::post('/{id}', [admin\adminController::class, 'deleteAdvertisement'])->name('delete-adv');


});```
````